# Cisco IOS/XR/NXOS, determine what's plugged into each port using arp, interfaces, and mac address-table

Tags: networking, cisco, local-area-network

I need to try to map out the access layer switches for this environment, and determine what each port is currently being used for. My ultimate goal here is to determine the IP address/hostname of the device connected to each switchport, or the mac/port number if it's a connection to another switch.  I collected each interface status (sh int brie), each of the switches mac addy tables (sh mac address-table) and arp results (sh ip arp).

Looking at all of this and trying to triangulate what is what, is incredibly confusing.

My process is to look at what interfaces are up. Next determine which interfaces are access or trunk. Note the mac address for each interface. Looking at the mac addr table of other switches, determine which ports are direct links to other switch ports, and try to follow the arp request to directly connected hosts. This has not been very successful, and a lot of information to process.

Questions:

Are there any other commands that would provide me other relevant or useful information that I am not using/not aware of?

Is this really the only way to map out the ports of a switch without having any further knowledge or details?

Any help is greatly appreciated.